# After updating to Ubuntu 16.04, Eclipse no longer works

Tags: eclipse

Since I updated from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, Eclipse has stopped working.  When I open files in Eclipse and choose Java Project, it hangs and doesn't do anything.  If I chose Options from the menu, it doesn't work either.

Any suggestions on how to get Eclipse to load my projects properly in Ubuntu 16.04, or any changes I should be aware of that could be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you add details to the issue.

Comment: We get a lot of questions here. We need more information to help us help you. How did you update to 16.04? What does "not working" mean? Can you open it and there's an issue? Or does it not open? Have you tried to open it with the terminal? What have you tried to do to get it working? Have you updated your applications after installing 16.04?

Comment: When I open eclipse from terminal it doesn't open and when I open my another eclipse Mars 2 from from file it opens but doesn't work. And before updating Ubuntu it was working very fine

Comment: Did you try reinstalling eclipse?

Comment: Yes I reinstalled eclipse still it  do not work after reinstalling , same problem occur